# Cloud hosting with multiple SSL Certificates

Tags: cloud-hosting

Can anyone suggest a US based cloud hosting option that allows multiple SSL certificates to be installed on a single account? Preferably a single vhost.

Was going to use Media Temple's Grid Service but they only allow a single SSL certificate.

I'm hoping to find a cloud service that allows a single virtual host to have multiple IP addresses on a single account, with multiple SSL Certificates on that single account.

Comment: SSL certificates are issued by domain and IP - unless you have a UCC certificate, which allows for more than one domain. In short, you'll need a separate account with its own IP address to host each SSL.

Comment: I'm sure you could setup a vhost with multiple IP addresses?

Comment: Your question is regarding finding a web hosting company that would allow more than one SSL on an account. I doubt you'll find that, since IP's are either shared on several accounts, or assigned to one account. If you have a dedicated server, then you can add multiple IP's, so that each vhost can have its own SSL.

Comment: hmmmmm yes, that's what I'm starting to discover - thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: No problem, good luck!